# How do I change the container to only take up half the page?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and I would like to make it to where half the page has thumbnails on the left, and the other half will show results when those thumbnails are clicked.  However, I can not seem to figure out how to make the container only be on the left-side of the page (essentially 50% of the page).  Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show research effort. Nobody here is going to feel compelled to write the entirety of this markup for you.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nV5rW/

Comment: I've only been doing html for a day and am completely self-teaching, so I am very new to the subject.  I have been researching but am still confused on how to do it.  I tried going into bootstrap.css and changing the .container to left:50% and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/PrSUL/

*HTML*

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<div id="left">
    <div class="padding">
        <ul>
            <li class="menuItem" id="one">One</li>
            <li class="menuItem" id="two">Two</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <div class="padding">
        <div id="oneItem" class="rightPanel">This is one</div>
        <div id="twoItem" class="rightPanel">This is two</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#left {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:50%;
    background-color:#dddddd;
}
#right {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:50%;
    background-color:#444444;
    color:white;
}
/*Reason for adding div just for padding is because if you add padding
to the div getting 50% width, the padding is added to the width, thus 
your width would be 50% + padding instead of 50%*/
 .padding {
    margin:10px;
}
ul {
    margin-top:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
li {
    margin-left:-40px;
    border:2px solid #ffffff;
    padding:7px;
    display:block;
}
li:hover {
    background-color:#444444;
    color:white;
}
.rightPanel {
    display:none;
}
```

*JS*

```
$(".menuItem").mouseover(function(){
    var myId = this.id;
    $("#"+myId+"Item").show();
});
$(".menuItem").mouseout(function(){
    var myId = this.id;
    $("#"+myId+"Item").hide();
});
```